# How to display page first then load custom fonts?

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have a time-sensitive webpage and I would wish it to display the page first, before loading any custom fonts. In other words, the page would first be displayed as though the fonts are not loaded.

This means that the custom fonts (if cached by the browser) would only be used when the user visits the page on the second and subsequent times.

I have tried:

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontName'; 
    src: url('http://domain.com/fonts/font.ttf');
}
</style>
```

But it does not *post-load* the fonts. This means that page-loading is delayed.

What may be some solutions / hacks to achieve this functionality *without Javascript*?

Comment: Could you alter the style via jquery/js after page load?

Comment: @BrianAdkins, no JavaScript.....

Comment: D'oh! ... Completely missed that.

Comment: So you have a time-sensitive webpage and you want to load heavy external binary blobs like fonts. Well that's sweet you want to get both under one hat, but did you ever consider that this does not work at all?

Comment: @hakre, The fonts would be optional supplement. In effect, I would like to have priority given to reducing page loading duration.

Comment: @Pacerier: No such thing exists if you don't script it. You can a bit of control that via server-side scripting, however as I already answered, you should prevent that at all costs.

Comment: @hakre, yes I mean of course, this question is about *how* do we script it to achieve that functionality.

Comment: @Pacerier: Please define *fully load the page*. Isn't the font part of the fully loaded page? Or asked back the other way around: Isn't the HTML always fully loaded *before* the font?

Comment: @hakre, I've added the details in the post.

Comment: @Pacerier: Fonts are normally loaded after the HTML, this is commonly known as FOUT. So technically you should not have any speed problem at all (because commonly the problem is inverse). Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

> What may be some solutions to achieve this functionality without Javascript?

**Not Possible.** You can not load the full page and then load the font while the font is part of the full page. That's contradicting into itself.

With javascript you could change the page so have one full page and then make it even "fuller".

Comment: What would "some solutions" look like?

Answer (score 0):

That's a tough one ... But here's an out-of-the-box kludgy idea... No idea if it works and it's probably going to get down-voted. :

Use 2 pages that are nearly identical:

1. Load page 'A' that uses no custom fonts except for a bit of text at the very bottom rendered using an inline style using the custom font.  Hopefully this give the browser a chance to cache the font.
2. Redirect without js (meta-refresh?) to page 'B' which has identical content except for the cached font applied.

Without js, though, I can't think of a way to time this correctly, so you're stuck in a race condition.

Comment: But even the bit of text at the bottom would require the browser to pre-download the fonts, defeating the purpose of trying to post-load fonts...